# How to return an object from an array if it doesn't have a key using .map()

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with Dialogflow, and I would like to return the speech value for the object in the messages array that does not have a platform key assigned to it:

```
"messages": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "skype",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "line",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "facebook",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "telegram",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "kik",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "FOO"
    }
  ]
```

Currently, I'm returning the value via this ugly process:

```
messages = messages[messages.length - 1].speech;
```

My concern is that I do not want to rely on the array returning the platform neutral message as the last element.

Currently, this is what I tried:

```
 console.log(messages.map(function(obj) {
    if (!(obj.hasOwnProperty('platform'))){
      return obj;
    }
  }));
```

But I receive an error that states `TypeError: messages.map is not a function`

How should the map function be designed for such a case

Comment: check what type is messages (what's its constructor), it might not be an array... you can also try iterating it using forEach, for, etc.

Comment: `messages.messages.filter(m => !m.hasOwnProperty('platform').map(m => m.speech);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

You can just loop through messages and look for what you're looking for. Here's a working solution:

```js
var messages =  [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "skype",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "line",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "facebook",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "telegram",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "kik",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "FOO"
    }
  ]
  for(var obj in messages){
    if(!(messages[obj].hasOwnProperty('platform'))){
        alert(messages[obj].speech);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

You can use the `filter` and `map` functions together. Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var messages =  [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "skype",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "line",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "facebook",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "telegram",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "kik",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "FOO"
    }
  ]
  var result = messages.filter(function(obj){
    if (!(obj.hasOwnProperty('platform'))){
      return obj;
    }
}).map(m => m.speech);

alert(result);
```

Comment: Yup, it's solution 2 what I was looking for. And it's a good solution since it'll return any possible instances where platform does not exist in the object.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code above I imagine that you have something like this.  I think that you are running map on a Map/Associative Array (or JS object) and map doesn't run on that object.  Below is a revised sample of what I think will work for you.

```js
let messageMap = {"messages": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "skype",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "line",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "facebook",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "telegram",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "platform": "kik",
      "speech": "FOO"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "FOO"
    }
  ]};
  
  // Filter out the messages that don't have a platform defined.
  let platformlessMessages = messageMap['messages'].filter((message) => {
  
    // Return a list of all messages where platform doesn't exists or isn't defined.
    return message.platform === undefined;
  });
  
  console.log(platformlessMessages); // Do whatever you want with that list of objects.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `messages` is actually defined as an array, I would suggest using the `find` function instead of `map`.  For example:

```
console.log(messages.find(function (obj) {
  return !obj.hasOwnProperty('platform');
}));
```

See also:

[How to find first element of array matching a boolean condition in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457264/how-to-find-first-element-of-array-matching-a-boolean-condition-in-javascript)

Comment: But this will return only the first instance, correct? Or will it return multiple instances like map?

Comment: After reading the docs for find, this answer is good only if I want the first instance, but it doesn't return all possible answers (what map does): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find