# Postman get value from JSON where equals a value in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

Currently using the latest version of Postman: 6.7.4 (Latest)

I'm trying to get a value out of a JSON response body and store it in an environment variable BUT the value 'username' should be equal to my preferred username.

Normally I would extract a value like this:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("useridToken", jsonData.Customers[0].userid);
```

This would give me the first item in the list but I do **not** wish to obtain the first nor the second item from the list. I wish to obtain the `userid` **where** `username` **EQUAL** "Billy" for example.

Output of the body response:

```
{
"Customers": [
    {
        "id": 24,
        "userid": 73063,
        "username": "BOB",
        "firstname": "BOB",
        "lastname": "LASTNAME
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "userid": 73139,
        "username": "Billy",
        "firstname": "Billy",
        "lastname": "lasty"
    }
   ]
}
```

Any tips?

I remember in SoapUI it was like this:

```
$.channels[?(@.is_archived=='false')].id[0]
```

I guess it's not possible to do this in JS in Postman?

Comment: [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (this question has nothing to do with postman or JSON btw, it's about finding a specific element in an array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find first element of array matching a boolean condition in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457264/how-to-find-first-element-of-array-matching-a-boolean-condition-in-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const data = {
  "Customers": [{
      "id": 24,
      "userid": 73063,
      "username": "BOB",
      "firstname": "BOB",
      "lastname": "LASTNAME"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "userid": 73139,
      "username": "Billy",
      "firstname": "Billy",
      "lastname": "lasty"
    }
  ]
}

const user = data.Customers.find(u => u.username === 'Billy')
const userid = user ? user.userid : 'not found'

console.log(user)
console.log(userid)
```

Comment: This works but whenever I change 'Billy' with an variable {{username}} in Postman it doesn't work?

Comment: You should check how to properly use dynamic variables within Postman

Comment: I got it too work nvm :p I'll mark this as the answer, since you were first!

Answer (score 4):

`find()` as another answer points out is the best solution here, but if the username is not unique and you want an array of users where username is 'Billy' then use `filter()`

```js
const jsonData = {
  "Customers": [{
      "id": 24,
      "userid": 73063,
      "username": "BOB",
      "firstname": "BOB",
      "lastname": "LASTNAME"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "userid": 73139,
      "username": "Billy",
      "firstname": "Billy",
      "lastname": "lasty"
    }
  ]
}
console.log(jsonData.Customers.filter(c => c.username === 'Billy'))
```

Comment: Notice that `Array.prototype.filter()` is not performant because it will filter the entire `array`.. And you need to find only the first one because `username` is unique

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I already stated that `.find()` is better, and use `.filter()` when username is not unique. Moreover, you are assuming that the username is unique since the question does not provide that information.

Answer (score 4):

In Postnam test script, you can use `some` Javascript features. In your case, too many way to do.
I will show you how to solve your case with `Array.find` function:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var user = jsonData.Customers.find(function(user) {
    return user.username === 'Billy';
    // OR you could config username in postman env
    // return user.username === pm.variables.get("username_to_find"); 
});
pm.environment.set("useridToken", user.userid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `userid` can also be obtained using `filter` as follows -

```js
const data = {
  "Customers": [{
      "id": 24,
      "userid": 73063,
      "username": "BOB",
      "firstname": "BOB",
      "lastname": "LASTNAME"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "userid": 73139,
      "username": "Billy",
      "firstname": "Billy",
      "lastname": "lasty"
    }
  ]
};
const username = 'Billy';
const user = data.Customers.filter(obj => obj.username.toLowerCase() === username.toLowerCase())[0];
const userid = user ? user['userid'] : null;

console.log(userid);
```

**Note:** `.toLowerCase()` is optional here, you may use it depending on your condition.

Then you could simply set it as -

```
pm.environment.set("useridToken", userid);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by the
[other answer that outputs an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902074).
<sup>1</sup>

It is not clearly stated by the original poster whether the desired output
should be a *single* `userid` (presumably the first occurence?) - or
an array containing *all* `userid`:s matching "Billy".

This answer shows a solution to the latter case by using
[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs).

### ```js
const jsonData = {
  Customers: [{
    userid: 73063,
    username: 'BOB'
  }, {
    userid: 73138,
    username: 'Billy'
  }, {
    userid: 74139,
    username: 'Billy'
  }]
};

const userIds = [];
_.forEach(_.filter(jsonData.Customers, c => c.username === 'Billy'),
  item => { userIds.push(item.userid); });
console.log(userIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.js"></script>
```

<sup>1</sup> That answer is quite helpful as it hints how to filter out
the relevant objects of the `Customers` array. However, the original poster
wants (an array of) the `userid`(s) which is a *number*, and not an an array
of *objects* that *contains* the `userid`:s. This is how my answer here is
different.

Comment: this was actually the best solution for me as the .find syntax was not coming up as an option only the .filter was working. thanks @henke

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const userid = data.Customers.find(u => u.username === 'Billy') || 'not found';
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating
[the currently highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901980),
slightly modified.
Also adding a solution inspired by
[the other Lodash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902650).<sup>1</sup>

```js
const jsonData = {
  Customers: [{
    id: 24,
    userid: 73063,
    username: 'BOB',
    firstname: 'BOB',
    lastname: 'LASTNAME'
  }, {
    id: 25,
    userid: 73139,
    username: 'Billy',
    firstname: 'Billy',
    lastname: 'lasty'
  }]};
for (const i in jsonData.Customers) {
  console.log('userid of customer['+i+']: '+jsonData.Customers[i].userid);
}
const userId_UsingFind = (name) => {
  const user = jsonData.Customers.find(item => item.username === name);
  return user ? user.userid : user;
};
console.log('Using .find(), userid of "Billy": '+userId_UsingFind('Billy'));
console.log('Using .find(), userid of "Joe": '+userId_UsingFind('Joe'));

const userId_Native = (name) => {
  for (const i in jsonData.Customers) {
    if (jsonData.Customers[i].username === name) {
      return jsonData.Customers[i].userid;
    }
  }
};
console.log('Native loop, userid of "Billy": '+userId_Native('Billy'));
console.log('Native loop, userid of "Joe": '+userId_Native('Joe'));
```

As the code shows, the solution using `.find()` is both short and elegant.

---

<sup>1</sup> Assuming the desired outcome is the `userid` of the **first**
`Billy`. To retrieve an **array** of `userid`:s for **all** occurrences
of`Billy`, see the [answer that returns an array of userid:s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173521)
.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows a solution using the JavaScript library
[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach).
This is **not** meant as a recommendation, but merely to prove that it is
*possible* to use Lodash.
It is inspired by
[the other lodash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902650).<sup>1</sup>

```js
const jsonData = {
  Customers: [{
    id: 24,
    userid: 73063,
    username: 'BOB',
    firstname: 'BOB',
    lastname: 'LASTNAME'
  }, {
    id: 25,
    userid: 73139,
    username: 'Billy',
    firstname: 'Billy',
    lastname: 'lasty'
  }]
};

const userId_Lodash = (name) => {
  let userId;
  _.forEach(jsonData.Customers, (item) => {
    if (item.username === name) { userId = item.userid; }
  });
  return userId;
};
console.log('Lodash loop, userid of "Billy": ' + userId_Lodash('Billy'));
console.log('Lodash loop, userid of "Dave": ' + userId_Lodash('Dave'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.js"></script>
```

For the question at hand, I don't see any particular reason to use the Lodash
library.
But in other examples it could make all the more sense.

---

<sup>1</sup> The posted question does not state whether the desired outcome is
the *first* `userid` matching `Billy`, or *all* such userid:s.
This answer gives the **first** hit.