# How to improve quality of my javascript - given 2 json-format array

Tags: javascript

```js
const countryList = [{"countryId":1,"countryQuote":"USDKRW","countryCode":"KRW","countryName":"\uD55C\uAD6D"},{"countryId":2,"countryQuote":"USDJPY","countryCode":"JPY","countryName":"\uC77C\uBCF8"},{"countryId":3,"countryQuote":"USDPHP","countryCode":"PHP","countryName":"\uD544\uB9AC\uD540"}];
const currencyQuoteList = [{"countryQuote":"USDKRW","currencyRate":1162.685028},{"countryQuote":"USDJPY","currencyRate":104.40402},{"countryQuote":"USDPHP","currencyRate":48.480296}];

let itemId = 1;
let countryQuote;
let countryRate;

countryList.forEach(element => {
    if(itemId == element.countryId) {
        countryQuote = element.countryQuote;
    }
});
console.log("countryQuote : " + countryQuote);

currencyQuoteList.forEach(element => {
    if(countryQuote == element.countryQuote) {
        countryRate = element.currencyRate;
    }
})
console.log("countryRate : " + countryRate);
```

I would like to find `currencyRate` using `itemId`.

Const values are given by the server.

I have a `countryId` in HTML, and I'd like to find `currencyRate` With these 2 arrays.

Each `countryQuote` key in arrays would be joinable.

I just have to find `currencyRate` using brute-force searching, but I would like to improve this code.

What should do I search for it?

Comment: I have been searching this subject for 2 hours, but I cannot still take proper answer. T.T

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I created snippet editor. Is this the result what you told ?

Comment: All answers are my favorites but I cannot accept all of them. I just accepted the oldest answer, and clicked useful thumb up to all of answers. Thanks for the quick answer. !!

Comment: @Christopher Can you do something (server side) for joining the two information?

Comment: @CarloCorradini I considered that way but I just think "how to hand this problem beautifully in javascript" at this time. ^_^ ;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Does this solution can suit your needs?

Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of *forEach* :)

I have added a little bit of checks for undefined values.

```js
const countryList = [{"countryId":1,"countryQuote":"USDKRW","countryCode":"KRW","countryName":"\uD55C\uAD6D"},{"countryId":2,"countryQuote":"USDJPY","countryCode":"JPY","countryName":"\uC77C\uBCF8"},{"countryId":3,"countryQuote":"USDPHP","countryCode":"PHP","countryName":"\uD544\uB9AC\uD540"}];
const currencyQuoteList = [{"countryQuote":"USDKRW","currencyRate":1162.685028},{"countryQuote":"USDJPY","currencyRate":104.40402},{"countryQuote":"USDPHP","currencyRate":48.480296}];

// The item identifier
const itemId = 1;

// Search country using itemId
const country = countryList.find(c => c.countryId === itemId);

if(country !== undefined) {
  // Country found

  // Search a match in currencyQuote using countryQuote found
  const currency = currencyQuoteList.find(c => c.countryQuote === country.countryQuote);
  
  if(currency !== undefined) {
    // Currency found !!!
    console.log(`Country: ${country.countryQuote}`)
    console.log(`Currency Rate: ${currency.currencyRate}`);
  } else {
    // Currency not found
    console.log("Invalid countryQuote :(");
  }
} else {
  // Country not found
  console.log("Invalid itemId :(");
}
```

PS: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457264/how-to-find-first-element-of-array-matching-a-boolean-condition-in-javascript): *"Since ES6 there is the native find method for arrays; **this stops enumerating the array once it finds the first match and returns the value.**"*

**So, using *find* is far more efficient (if found) rather than check every single element in the array.**

Comment: My answer used a `filter()`, but I think your `find()` solution is better here. Upvoted for that!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a built-in `filter` function for Arrays.  [Use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const countryList = [{"countryId":1,"countryQuote":"USDKRW","countryCode":"KRW","countryName":"\uD55C\uAD6D"},{"countryId":2,"countryQuote":"USDJPY","countryCode":"JPY","countryName":"\uC77C\uBCF8"},{"countryId":3,"countryQuote":"USDPHP","countryCode":"PHP","countryName":"\uD544\uB9AC\uD540"}];
const currencyQuoteList = [{"countryQuote":"USDKRW","currencyRate":1162.685028},{"countryQuote":"USDJPY","currencyRate":104.40402},{"countryQuote":"USDPHP","currencyRate":48.480296}];

let itemId = 1;
//let countryQuote;
let countryRate;

//this one line replaces your first forEach loop
let country = countryList.filter(countryCode => countryCode.countryId == itemId)[0];

//show result of first filter
console.log("country:");
console.log(country);

//this one line replaces your 2nd forEach loop
let quote = currencyQuoteList.filter(element => element.countryQuote == country.countryQuote)[0];
countryRate = quote.currencyRate;

//show result of 2nd filter
console.log("countryRate : " + countryRate);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the JavaScript [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function you could simply filter the `country` with the specific `countryId` from your `countryList` array. Then filter the `currencyQuoteList` by `countryQuote` to add the `currencyRate` property to your `country` object.

*e.g.* let's suppose that `countryId` is 2:

```js
const countryList = [{
  "countryId": 1,
  "countryQuote": "USDKRW",
  "countryCode": "KRW",
  "countryName": "\uD55C\uAD6D"
}, {
  "countryId": 2,
  "countryQuote": "USDJPY",
  "countryCode": "JPY",
  "countryName": "\uC77C\uBCF8"
}, {
  "countryId": 3,
  "countryQuote": "USDPHP",
  "countryCode": "PHP",
  "countryName": "\uD544\uB9AC\uD540"
}];
const currencyQuoteList = [{
  "countryQuote": "USDKRW",
  "currencyRate": 1162.685028
}, {
  "countryQuote": "USDJPY",
  "currencyRate": 104.40402
}, {
  "countryQuote": "USDPHP",
  "currencyRate": 48.480296
}];
let countryId = 2;
let country = countryList.filter(c => c.countryId == countryId)[0];
country.currencyRate = currencyQuoteList.filter(cq => cq.countryQuote == country.countryQuote)[0].currencyRate;
console.log(country);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a little different way that first join both the arrays and create a single array with the consolidated details using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then find based on `countryId`

```js
const countryList = [{countryId:1,countryQuote:'USDKRW',countryCode:'KRW',countryName:'\uD55C\uAD6D',},{countryId:2,countryQuote:'USDJPY',countryCode:'JPY',countryName:'\uC77C\uBCF8',},{countryId:3,countryQuote:'USDPHP',countryCode:'PHP',countryName:'\uD544\uB9AC\uD540',},];
const currencyQuoteList = [{countryQuote:'USDKRW',currencyRate:1162.685028},{countryQuote:'USDJPY',currencyRate:104.40402},{countryQuote:'USDPHP',currencyRate:48.480296},];


const formatData = data => {
  const finalRes = data.reduce((res, {
    countryQuote,
    ...rest
  }) => {
    res[countryQuote] = {
      ...res[countryQuote],
      ...rest,
    };

    return res;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(finalRes);
};

const formattedData = formatData([...countryList, ...currencyQuoteList]);
//console.log(formattedData);

let itemId = 1;

const getItemById = (data, id) => data.find(({countryId}) => countryId === id)

console.log("ID = 1 then currencyRate: ",getItemById(formattedData, itemId)?.currencyRate);
console.log("ID = 2 then currencyRate: ", getItemById(formattedData, 2)?.currencyRate);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment :) It's really helpful to me.